# Magento 1.7 Override Pdf Classes

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I tried to override Pdf classes for making changes toInvoice/Shipment/Creditmemo pdf but it doesnt seem to reflect.

I created a module with following in the Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mymodule_Printtemplates>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mymodule_Printtemplates>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order_pdf_abstract>Mymodule_Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract</order_pdf_abstract>
                <order_pdf_invoice>Mymodule_Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                <order_pdf_creditmemo>Mymodule_Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Creditmemo</order_pdf_Creditmemo>
                <order_pdf_shipment>Mymodule_Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment</order_pdf_shipment>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
</global>
```

Then I created following Model classes in Mymodule/models/
as Abstract.php, Invoice.php, Shipment.php, Creditmemo.php

```
abstract class Mymodule_Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract

class  Mymodule_Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends  Mymodule__Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract { ... functions here ...}

class Mymodule_Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment extends Mymodule__Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract{ ... functions here ...}

class Mymodule_Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Creditmemo  extends  Mymodule__Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract{ ... functions here ...}
```

The module is enabled - I have checked it through System>Configuration>Admin>Advanced but it doesn't seem to reflect the changes

On the other-hand, if I copy paste Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/*.php into local and change, changes are reflected. I know this is not a recommended method but the method via rewriting classes doesnt seem to work.

Any help for the first method via class rewrite would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Loveleen

---

The real problem was a Syntax in error in etc/config.xml [see Capital C in  ending tag]

> Mymodule_Printtemplates_Model_Order_Pdf_Creditmemo

I used the following to debug the issue: Drop this in the bottom of your index.php, similar to Alans Module List but a quick code copy/paste approach. Remember all of Magento's XML's get combined into one XML tree.

header("Content-Type: text/xml"); die(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML());

Taken from the answers of: [How do I know whether my Config.xml file is working in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835275/how-do-i-know-whether-my-config-xml-file-is-working-in-magento)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of things that I am seeing.

1. What are the file paths to each of your overridden files? They should be: `Mymodule/Printtemplates/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`, for example. The class name should match the file name.
2. Rewrites do not affect abstract classes, unless the abstract class is called with a factory method (not recommended). The way that a rewrite works is through the factory methods (`Mage::getModel('')`). Using the factory method allows Magento to look through the system to see if another class is needing to be used. However, when a class is hard-referenced (e.x. `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract`), it does not go through the factory method, and thus no rewrites will occur on that.
3. I would consider making each of your classes extend their original class (e.x. `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice`, etc). If you have extra common functions, you would possibly put those into a Helper.
4. To see if the code is even being called, put a known code error in the file. PHP will complain, and that tells you that your file is being loaded.

Comment: Thanks Jmax! I'll try what you propose.

Comment: Please remember to mark as answered if it answers your question.

Comment: You gave a good checklist. But the real problem was that the ending tag of one of the tags in etc/config xml had an error. </order_pdf_Creditmemo> has a Capitalized C

Comment: Ah. I didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used the following to debug the issue:
Drop this in the bottom of your index.php, similar to Alans Module List but a quick code copy/paste approach. Remember all of Magento's XML's get combined into one XML tree.

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
die(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML());

Taken from the answers of: [How do I know whether my Config.xml file is working in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835275/how-do-i-know-whether-my-config-xml-file-is-working-in-magento)