# Magento: limit 3 products from category per order

Tags: magento

I'm trying to set up a sample products category in Magento to allow people to select up to 3 free samples for every purchase, but how can I limit only 3 samples from that category per order?

[EDIT]

This is the current config.xml inside the dir app/code/local/MagePal/LimitCartProductByCategory/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <limitcartproductbycategory>
            <class>MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory_Model_Observer</class>
        </limitcartproductbycategory>
    </models>
     <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <limitcartproductbycategory>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>cartlimit</method>
                </limitcartproductbycategory>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
</global>
</config>
```

MagePal_EnableDuplicateProductStatus.xml in dir app/etc/modules/MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory>
</modules>
</config>
```

This is the current Observer.php inside the dir app/code/local/MagePal/LimitCartProductByCategory/Model/Observer.php:

```
class MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory_Model_Observer 
{

public function cartlimit(Varien_Event_Observer  $observer)
{
    $category_ids = array();

    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
          $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
          $product_category_ids = explode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
          //$product_category_ids = $product->getCategoryIds();

          array_push($category_ids, $product_category_ids);
    }

    $justAdded = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $justAddedCategoryIds = explode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
    $justAddedId = in_array(58, $justAddedCategoryIds);


    $productJustAdded = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($justAdded->getId());

    //total the catalogegory id in $category_ids
    //if $productJustAdded->getCategoryIds exist in $category_ids, 
    //then check to see if category id count greater than 3
    // if true then add error msg and try setting the qty to 0

    $freesample = 58;
    $tmp = array_count_values($category_ids);
    $cnt = $tmp[$freesample];

    echo $cnt;

    if ($justAddedId == true && $cnt > 3) {

        $quote->removeItem($justAdded->getId())->save();
        Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages('You can only have 3 free samples. Please remove a sample to add another.');
        Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an observer for event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

Take a look at my example @ [Change Magento default status for duplicated products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677971/change-magento-default-status-for-duplicated-products) for help on how to create on observer

```
     <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <enableduplicateproductstatus>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>limitcartproductbycategory/observer</class>
                    <method>cartlimit</method>
                </enableduplicateproductstatus>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
```

Create: app/code/local/MagePal/LimitCartProductByCategory/Model/Observer.php

```
class MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory_Model_Observer 
{

    public function cartlimit(Varien_Event_Observer  $observer)
    {
        $category_ids = array();

        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
              $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
              $product_category_ids = explode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
              //$product_category_ids = $product->getCategoryIds();

              array_push($category_ids, $product_category_ids);
        }

        $justAdded = $observer->getQuoteItem();


        $productJustAdded = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($justAdded->getId());

        //total the category id in $category_ids
        //if $productJustAdded->getCategoryIds exist in $category_ids, 
        //then check to see if category id count greater than 3
        // if true then add error msg and try setting the qty to 0

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something I'm missing cause I added both of these files plus my code, and I'm still not getting a response. I'm not too familiar with observes but from what I've read and your other post I have everything in the right spot. app>code>local>MagePal>LimitCartProductByCategory @R.S

Comment: The files should be in `app/code/local/MagePal/LimitCartProductByCategory/*` and not app/code/local/LimitCartProductByCategory/*

Comment: Sorry i had them in that directory i just forgot to add MagePal in the edit

Comment: The problem is you are using two different module name <CompanyName_ModuleName> should equal to  app/code/local/CompanyName/ModuleName/*. So <MagePal_EnableDuplicateProductStatus>,  MagePal/LimitCartProductByCategory is not correct. Should be <MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory>,  MagePal/LimitCartProductByCategory. (replace all 'enableduplicateproductstatus' and 'EnableDuplicateProductStatus' need to replace with the corresponding case)

Comment: I made these changes, flushed cache, and still not seeing the changes. Thanks @R.S for you help so far, i'm just trying to learn this. I reflected everything in the edit.

Comment: Is your module installed/loaded? Is your observer been trigger try using `die('LimitCartProductByCategory - observer called')`; or `Mage::log('LimitCartProductByCategory - observer called');` in `public function cartlimit()`?

Comment: I hate to ask this but how do I go about installing this module? thanks

Comment: Admin system > configuration > advanced tab and see if your module name appears. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835275/how-do-i-know-whether-my-config-xml-file-is-working-in-magento

Comment: i've never use a debugger for magento.

Comment: Goto Admin -> system > configuration > advanced tab ... do you see 'LimitCartProductByCategory' listed?

Comment: I just tested the config and it was listed in the advanced tab, so it either you have cache enable or some other incorrect config

Comment: hmm, well i have cache turned off cause i'm still tweaking the site, i don't understand what is up with this. Thank you so much for your help by the way

Comment: Try testing using (Method 2 - Creating a Custom Module) from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720431/magento-remove-promo-item . then log into admin, check to see if the promo menu is still there?

Comment: After i fixed a syntax mistake it is gone @R.S

Comment: so if your remove promo item works then why won't it recognize this other config file? @R.S

Comment: Try adding the observer code to the promo and once you get it working then do a find and replace to rename

Comment: I think everything is up and working, I can see it in the advanced tab, but I can't even get something to just echo out after an item has been added to the cart... @R.S

Comment: does ajax ignore observer unless it's referenced by ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You should write an observer that observes the cart and checks that only 3 samples are put to it.

Here an example

```
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <tibdev_fancybox_cart_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Tibdev_Fancybox_Model_Cart_Observer</class>
                    <method>applyFancybox</method>
                </tibdev_fancybox_cart_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

Here you can see my observer that observes the event checkout_cart_product_add_after.

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm not familiar with this. How would I use it and where would that be located?

Comment: Are you a developer? Have a look at Alan Storms tutorial site. If you aren't a developer you can contact me.