# Magento get number of items in cart by category

Tags: magento

I am attempting to get the number of items in the users cart, by each category. Any help would be must appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Magento: limit 3 products from category per order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345619/magento-limit-3-products-from-category-per-order)

```
.....
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
      $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
      $product_category_ids = explode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
      //$product_category_ids = $product->getCategoryIds();

      foreach($product_category_ids as $category_id){
           $category_ids[$category_id]['category_id'] = $category_id;
           $category_ids[$category_id]['product_count'] = ($category_ids[$category_id]['product_count']) ? $category_ids[$category_id]['product_count'] + $item->getQty() : $item->getQty();
      }
}
```