# Limit order quantity by category or add additional shipping charge by category in Magento

Tags: magento

I have an issue with Magento.

I have a category where the customers can buy only one product from that category per order. I have successfully set the settings such that only one item can be added in the product settings. However, if  the customer goes back to that category, he is still able to add another product in that category. Say he selects Product A from Category A, he can return to Category A to select Product B. What I want is at all times, for that order, he can buy only one Product from Category A.

If this is not possible, I wish to add additional shipping charge if more than 1 product is chosen from that category.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

See [Magento: limit 3 products from category per order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345619/magento-limit-3-products-from-category-per-order)

Create an observer for event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

```
     <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <enableduplicateproductstatus>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>limitcartproductbycategory/observer</class>
                    <method>cartlimit</method>
                </enableduplicateproductstatus>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
```

Create: app/code/local/MagePal/LimitCartProductByCategory/Model/Observer.php

```
class MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory_Model_Observer 
{

    public function cartlimit(Varien_Event_Observer  $observer)
    {
        $category_ids = array();

        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
              $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
              $product_category_ids = explode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
              //$product_category_ids = $product->getCategoryIds();

              array_push($category_ids, $product_category_ids);
        }

        $justAdded = $observer->getQuoteItem();


        $productJustAdded = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($justAdded->getId());

        //total the category id in $category_ids
        //if $productJustAdded->getCategoryIds exist in $category_ids, 
        //then check to see if category id count greater than 3
        // if true then add error msg and try setting the qty to 0

        return $this;
    }
}
```